# Playhead movement increment is too large in DaVinci Resolve 18

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am trying to move the playhead a small amount to trim a clip with a very fine cut. Howerver, the playhead can only move in relatively large increments. Here is a gif to demonstrate the problem:

[image: playhead granularity]

Has anyone got an idea how fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you're limited by the frame rate, it cant move between frames, if you play the clip the minimum gap will be a single frame